# Simplest way to publish WFS from SQL Server under ASP.NET

Tags: c#, wfs, asp.net

My environment is ASP.NET, with data stored in SQL Server.  Is there a way to serve Web Feature Services through C#, or will I need to install a mapping server?

Answer (score 4):

You will need a mapping server unless you want to implement the entire WFS protocol which is *highly* not recommended.

Comment: Yes, I agree with the principle, though am using Asure services, which doesn't offer me the ability to install server software.  I want to tack the functionality onto an existing product.

Comment: Well, then you are going to need to find a *pure* .NET Server WFS implementation from somewhere. Having seen the immense amount of pain that came from the co-worker implementing WFS 1.1 for ESRI, I would caution against doing this. Most likely you are going to end up with a subset of WFS 1.1 at which point where it becomes questionable why you would even implement WFS at all and not go a simpler route.

Answer (score 2):

You could serve WFS (and WMS) from C# by using Mapserver [WxS mapscript wrappers]
[1](http://mapserver.org/ogc/mapscript.html#mapscript-wrappers-for-wxs-services).

They are available, among other languages, for C#.
Binary builds [here](https://www.gisinternals.com/sdk.php).

Answer (score 0):

You would need a mapping server as @Ragi mentioned. It just doesn't make sense to reimplement the whole stack.

You could start with Geoserver. According to the [OpenGeo site](http://opengeo.org/technology/geoserver/), it has the following features:

> - Implements OGC services including Web Map Service (WMS 1.1.1 and 1.3.0), Web Feature Service (WFS 1.0.0 and 1.1.0), WFS-Transactional (WFS-T 1.0.0), and Web Coverage Service (WCS 1.0.0 and 1.1.1) Java
>     J2EE application, works with Jetty, Tomcat, WebLogic, WebSphere, JBoss
> - **Support for many back-end data formats (ArcSDE, Oracle Spatial, DB2, SQL Server, shapefile, GeoTIFF, MrSID, JPEG2000)**
> - Multiple output formats (GML, shapefile, KML, GeoJSON, PNG, JPEG, TIFF, SVG, PDF, GeoRSS) plus Google Earth integration
> - Fully-featured and intuitive web administration interface with REST API for programmatic control
> - Full map styling support with Styled Layer Descriptor (SLD), including text-based and graphical editor User- and role-based
>     security subsystem based on Spring Security

I'm just curious though, does it have to be WFS?

Comment: While WMS will be ok in most situations, i would like to be able to serve at the feature level.