# Are there any exisiting .NET implementations for WFS that are extendable?

Tags: c#, open-source-gis, wfs, .net

I've been told its a bad idea to implement WFS from scratch: 
[Implementing WFS within .NET](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/67556/implementing-wfs-within-net?rq=1)

Does anybody know of any exisiting .net implementations that I can extend?

Comment: why do you need to extend a WFS?

Comment: We need to add support for m and z values. We may have some requirements for custom operations to custom fit our workflow.

Comment: Are you talking about a client, or a server ? And which ones have you tried, that doesn't support Z & M ? (GML ?)

Comment: I'm not sure how this helps me. Do you know of any customizable .NET implementations for WFS that I can extend? I am talking about the server side of things here. Please let me know if you know any.