# WFS implementation suggestion

Tags: wfs

I need to develop an interactive map (Show map and point with some related data) with OpenLayers from client side but from server side I don't know what I should use. GeoServer seems to be much more than what I need.

What I need is a service that accepts and it responds with WFS. Considering that I have access to the database that stores the transactional and georeferenced data.

Can I develop my own implementation of web service in PHP? Are there existing libraries? If not, what do you suggest?

Comment: [Everyone](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/67556/implementing-wfs-within-net) and [their dog](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/33667/simplest-way-to-publish-wfs-from-sql-server-under-asp-net) will tell you that writing your own is a 'bad idea' and you should use the servers that the OS community have refined over the years.  But, the [WFS spec](http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/wfs) is out there and if you're keen there's no reason why you shouldn't try for yourself if you have the skill and time.  Otherwise, keep to what's already been written.  AFAIK, there are none in PHP

Comment: @nagytech, thanks! Based on my needs, what server do you recommend?

Comment: @juls has provided a comparison of the different servers.  But, personally I believe GeoServer is the easiest and most flexible.  There is an example of how to use various databases as data sources [here](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/data/app-schema/data-stores.html#app-schema-data-stores) and an example for setting up a Layer [here](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/gettingstarted/postgis-quickstart/index.html).

Comment: Would recommend Geoserver is active and stable http://blog.geoserver.org/ with WFS (PostGIS required) http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/developer/cite-test-guide/index.html#run-wfs-1-0-tests

Answer (score 1):

take a look at : 
[Comparing different open source GIS servers?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/6604/comparison-of-the-different-open-source-gis-servers)

If you are familiar with python see also the geodjango framework :
[link here][1]

[1]https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/